# system() to execXX() and errors handling signals

Tags: c, linux, signals, exec, system

I'm trying to make a small program as exercise based on old exam papers. What the program has to do is:

1. 2≤N≤4 invocation arguments each of which are UNIX command (i.e. who, date).
2. Create N child process each of tem opening an xterm terminal executing each of the command given. The terminal must stay open until enter is hit.
3. If the process is closed normally (with enter) then re-open it
4. If the process/terminal is closed using signal just write a message

My only problem is the 4th point.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void catchsig(int sig){
    ;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int pid, exit_status, proc_id, p_proc_id;
    int proc[argc-1];
    char buf[1024];
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler = &catchsig;

    for (int i=0; i<argc-1; i++){
    proc[i]=0;
    }


/*Argument control*/
    if ((argc-1)<2){
    perror("Error");
    exit(1);
    }
    else if ((argc-1)>4){
    perror("Error");
    exit(1);
    }   


    for (int i=1; i<argc; i++){
        snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "xterm -e '%s;read'", argv[i]);
        if ((pid=fork())<0){
            perror("Error");
            exit(1);
        }
    /*child*/
        else if (pid==0 && proc[i-1]==0){
            int f;
            f = i-1;
            close(piped[1]);
            p_proc_id=getppid();
            proc_id = getpid();
            while (proc[f]==0){
                printf("Process %s; PID %d \n",argv[i], proc_id);

                exit_status = system(buf);
                printf("Process %s; exit status = %d; if exited = %d; WEXITSTATUS = %d; WIFSIGNALED = %d; WTERMSIG=%d\n", argv[i], exit_status, WIFEXITED(exit_status), WEXITSTATUS(exit_status), WIFSIGNALED(exit_status), WTERMSIG(exit_status));
                if (WIFSIGNALED(exit_status)){
                    proc[f]=1;
printf("Killed by signal");
}

}
                        

        }
    /*parent*/
            else{
;
                }
            }

    exit(0);
}
```

I think it's because I used `system()`, but sincerely, I don't know  how to replace it with an `execXX()` which does the same thing.
Thanks in advance!

Edit:
I tried re-write the code using `execl()` and `wait()` instead of `sysytem()`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


void catchsig(int sig){
    ;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int pid, proc_id, p_proc_id, status, stat;
    int piped[2];
    int proc[argc-1];
    char buf[1024], key;
    char buffe[argc];
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler = &catchsig;

    if (pipe(piped)<0){
        exit(1);    
    }

    for (int i=0; i<argc-1; i++){
    proc[i]=0;
    }

    status = 0;
/*Argument control*/
    if ((argc-1)<2){
    perror("Error");
    exit(1);
    }
    else if ((argc-1)>4){
    perror("Error");
    exit(1);
    }   

while (status == 0){
    for (int i=1; i<argc; i++){
        int f;
        f=i-1;
        snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s;read", argv[i]);
        if ((pid=fork())<0){
            perror("Errore fork");
            exit(1);
        }
    /*child*/
        else if (pid==0 && proc[f]==0){
            proc_id = getpid();
            printf("Process %s; PID %d \n",argv[i], proc_id);

            execl("/usr/bin/xterm", "/usr/bin/xterm",  "-e", buf, (void*)NULL);
                
                        

        }
    /*parent*/
            else{
                wait(&stat);
                printf("Process %s; exit status = %d; if exited = %d; WEXITSTATUS = %d; WIFSIGNALED = %d; WTERMSIG=%d\n", argv[i], stat, WIFEXITED(stat), WEXITSTATUS(stat), WIFSIGNALED(stat), WTERMSIG(stat));
                if (WIFSIGNALED(stat)){
                    proc[f]=1;
                    printf("Process closed \n");}
                for (int s=0; s<argc-1; s++){
                    if (proc[s]==1){
                        status=1;}
                    else if (proc[s]==0){
                        status=0;
                        break;}
            }

    }
    printf("status=%d \n", status);
            }
}
    exit(0);
}
```

Unfortunally the problems/limitations of this code are 2:

1. It can only open 1 xterm terminal at time.
2. I noticed that if just 1 child process remain and I keep closing it with enter, it will create more parents processes, each of them executing that child process.

Comment: "*don't know how to replace it with an execXX()*". Why not? Can you be more specific? Have you read the [exec manual](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html)? Have you looked for examples? Have you tried a small example program? After doing all that, what specific problem or non-understanding do you still have that we can help with?

Comment: How are you testing it?

Comment: I compile it and run it every time, no doubt it's the most inefficient way, but it works

Comment: i've looked up many examples, still when i try to run it in the best case it just show up for a second a terminal and then closes it exiting the program. I've tried using execl("/usr/bin/xterm", "/usr/bin/xterm", "-e", buf, (void*)NULL);

Comment: Compiling and running will not normally cause the program or terminal to exit with a signal. You have to explicitly trigger the signal. For example, you can run your program, wait for the terminal to pop up, run `xkill`, click the terminal, and then examine the return status.

Comment: yes, of course. But doing like that, with the code i gave and using the pid that the code gives me back, terminate the process without even close the xterm terminal

Comment: "*when i try*". Update the post to show exactly what you tried and what specific problem you had. That gives us something specific to answer rather than just "don't know how".

Comment: @Floppy In this case you are killing the process doing the signal check, instead of the terminal.